# Error in printing out the data obtained in pointer to character strings

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dll, printf

I am trying to call an interface function and print out the resulting values. The function prototype contains pointers to character string as arguments. When I print out the resulting values I receive some strange symbols. Is my below approach correct?

```
int interfacecall(char *a, char *b ...);

char * a= "Testdata";
char b [4098];

result= interfacecall(a,b);

//different value is returned in b via function implementation in a third party dll.

printf(b);
```

Comment: Well, for that we'd need to know what `interfacecall` actually does...

Comment: what does `interfacecall` do? also, try `char a[] = "Testdata";`

Comment: Also, `char * a = "literal"` is deprecated, either use `const char* a = "literal"` or `char a[] = "literal"`.

Comment: @Xeo: do you have a reference for the deprecated assignment of a string literal address to a pointer to char? Or you meant it's deprecated in `C++`? I believe all `C++` compilers must complain if you try to assign a string literal (of type `const char []`) to a pointer to char (type `char *`) *in `C`, string literals are of type `char[]`.*

Comment: @pmg: Meh, overlooked that lil `c` tag... Well then, my last comment only holds true for `C++` :)

Comment: Hmmm ... somebody correct me if I'm wrong ... in `C++` it is an error to assign a string literal to a `char *`, not just deprecated.

Comment: interfacecall would populate char *b parameter with some status messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf is not that safe. It should be :

```
printf("%s", b);  //corrected - safe!
```

In C++, you can also use `std::cout` as:

```
std::cout << b; //its simpler - must include<iostream>
```

Make sure that `b` is a null-terminated c-string, otherwise it wil print garbage and may crash your program.  Null-terminated string means it must end with `\0`.  Something like this:

```
b[slen] = '\0'; //you may have to do this explicitly!
```

Comment: Well, you *can* directly print without the format string. It's just not very save to do so, as one could inject all kind of mischievous code.

Comment: I tried using the null terminated string, yet I get garbage on printing out. Say i allocate an array of size 5000. If the returned data is populated only upto 2000 , and I added a null at 4999, would it result in printing garbage data ?

Comment: @vij: In that case how should I help you if you don't post your code?

Comment: @vij: Yes. from 2001 to 4998 is garbage!

Comment: char error[4097];result= callInterface(a, error,....);error[sizeof(error)-1]='\0';printf(error);

Comment: @vij: Post detail code in your post. also post what it prints.

Comment: I am printing to cmd prompt and this is what I see-the error_return contains╩N↔‼